# Object Mapper deserializing map array

Tags: java, objectmapper

```
   {
       "name" : "test",
       "info": [
          {
            "key1": "test",
            "key2": "blaa",
            "key3": "yadayada"
          },
          {
            "key4": "test1",
            "key5": "blaa1",
            "key6": "yadayada1"
          }
        ],
    }
```

I have this class for the deserialization

```
public class Account{
    private String name;
    private Map<String,String>[] info;
}
```

for some reason `info` is not getting deserialized... not even with `List<Map<String,String>>` its always null, and `name` is working

(im using `ObjectMapper`)

**the code**

```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   objectMapper.disable( DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
   results = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody.getEntity().getContent(), Account.class);
```

Thanks

Comment: *How* are you using `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: You mentioned `List<Map<String,String>>` but your code declares an array `Map<String,String>[]`, which one are you actually using ?

Comment: Add a stacktrace of the error you are getting, it will help to understand where your problem is

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I tried both of them. im getting null

Comment: @ScottHunter I added the code to the question

Comment: @MichaelGantman there is no error, im getting null

Comment: Provide minimal testcase then

Comment: There's probably no error because you disabled them, remove the line that calls `objectMapper.disable(...)`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel no error without the `disable`

Comment: Then they're plenty of other questions like `ObjectMapper readValue returns null` on SO, I think that your solution is probably in one of these

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel please read my question again, `readValue` is not returning null. the object gets deserialized successfully but `info` stays null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mixed bag of things wrong.

1. Your JSON is invalid - ditch the last comma after the closing square bracket
2. Your POJO shows no accessible methods to set the values (i.e. deserialize into an `Account`)
3. According to your post, the `name` field is de-serialized, which I imagine implies some accessible setter is actually there but you may not have posted it?
4. If the `info` silently fails to serialize, it's likely because your `ObjectMapper` has been configured with `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` as `false` - see [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES).
5. You can either have a `List<Map<String, String>>` for `info`, or keep the `Map<String, String>[]` - it's not relevant to your issue.

Comment: @SexyMF can happen to anyone :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the fact that **the JSON schema you posted has a wrong comma in the end**) . Try the following

Let's say that the `responseBody.getEntity().getContent()` is the `JSON` you posted

**Account.java**

or more specific

```
private String name;
private Map<String,String>[] info;
//getters && setters && default constructor
```

**Deserialization method**

```
    Account account = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        account = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody.getEntity().getContent(), Account.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what is the point of keeping nested json as `Object`. It's pretty unusable.

Comment: I propose a more specific data structure ( `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>` as you can see :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the data structure in use.

Comment: @Mena I think there was a different data structure than this one in the  example provided in the first place

Comment: @NickAth as far as I can see from the revision [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57310650/revisions), OP only provided `List<Map<String, String>>` and `Map<String, String>[]`, both of which would work with the JSON provided (as long as the last comma is removed as you noted too).

Comment: My bad then :) , as you can see I updated my answer pointing only on the real cause of the problem (`getters && setters and wrong comma in the JSON`)

Comment: @NickAth but the real reason is *a* missing (or as it turned out - non-accessible) setter and the lack of useful traces is due to the specific configuration of the `ObjectMapper`. Getters are irrelevant to this specific case since we're de-serializing, and the syntax issue is much more likely due to OP cropping a longer JSON for the scope of this example, otherwise they would definitely get traces with parsing issues.

Comment: As far as it would not be safe to assume that `syntax issue is much more likely due to OP cropping a longer JSON for the scope of this example` I  could not also assume that the OP would have a problem in the setter, just pointed some possible causes as you did too :) ( you are right the problem is not the getter since this is a deserialization issue but just mentioned a common practice in Models that have private member variables (add getters and setters)